# How to install Drivers for RS-232 for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb-modem, serial-port

I'm trying to install drivers for RS-232 . Can you help me with proper command or method?

In my PC when i'm giving lsmod its not showing the cdc_acm driver but i tried to install again it's showing driver is already there.

Using command modeprobe cdc_acm its displaying the driver.
How to solve this two issues?

I tried to give tail -f /var/log/syslog its showing the following errors how to fix this?

```
    root@yash20-desktop:/home/yash20# tail -f /var/log/syslog
Sep  5 10:27:19 yash20-desktop kernel: [   36.512190] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
Sep  5 10:27:38 yash20-desktop kernel: [   55.529151] audit_printk_skb: 42 callbacks suppressed
Sep  5 10:27:38 yash20-desktop kernel: [   55.529154] type=1400 audit(1536123458.500:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2423 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  5 10:27:38 yash20-desktop kernel: [   55.529161] type=1400 audit(1536123458.500:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2423 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  5 10:28:50 yash20-desktop kernel: [  127.759992] gvfsd-metadata[4220]: segfault at 7ffb6405c000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007ffe99258ff0 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.035233] gvfsd-metadata[4244]: segfault at 7f4272d13000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007ffccb5eebf0 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.224081] gvfsd-metadata[4250]: segfault at 7f5a9ded4000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007fff06f5e270 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.367639] gvfsd-metadata[4275]: segfault at 7f21625eb000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007fffe68e08c0 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.499979] gvfsd-metadata[4283]: segfault at 7facae55e000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007ffc36778990 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
Sep  5 10:30:18 yash20-desktop kernel: [  215.385526] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (6507) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: What hardware do you have? How do you connect it? Is it USB-RS232 converted? What does "IN" mean in your question?

Comment: I'm using ATSAMA5D36 board to connect with the PC. i'm using pl2303 serial converter for connecting this .

Comment: @N0rbert How can i install new drivers for cdc acm. thats my question.

Comment: New question should be asked with [*Ask Question* button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

As you are using PL2303-based serial USB converter, then you do not need to install driver manually.

The driver is already compiled and named `pl2303`:

```
$ modinfo pl2303 | head -n3
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-104-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Prolific PL2303 USB to serial adaptor driver
```

So you can simply connect USB cable to the PC and wait for appearance of `/dev/ttyUSB?` or `/dev/ttyACM?` in the system. The driver will be loaded automatically.

You can check `tail -f /var/log/syslog` for concrete name of the device. Below is the output just after USB-converter insertion:

> Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname kernel: [11751.607185] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
>   Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname kernel: [11751.735834] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
>   Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname kernel: [11751.735837] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>   Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname kernel: [11751.735839] usb 3-3: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
>   Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname kernel: [11751.735841] usb 3-3: **Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.**
>   Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
>   Sep  5 20:03:40 hostname mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.294821] **usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial**
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.294871] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.294914] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.299226] usbcore: registered new interface **driver pl2303**
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.299422] **usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303**
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.299466] pl2303 3-3:1.0: **pl2303 converter detected**
>   Sep  5 20:03:42 hostname kernel: [11753.300963] usb 3-3: **pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0**

Please note the last line **`pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0`**. It means that device is known as `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Do not forget to add your user to `dialout` group with

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Comment: I tried to give tail -f /var/log/syslog its showing the following errors on top how to fix that?

Comment: See update above - you need only specific lines from log.